# A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType '' does not declare a navigation property with the name ''

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I wonder if you could help. I get the above error when I call `.Include()`. It breaks when I include `tblMemberships`.

```
this.dbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
List<tblCustomerInfo> customers = this.dbContext.tblCustomerInfoes.Include("tblUsers").Include("tblMemberships").ToList();
```

The reason is because the navigation property between `tblCustomerInfo` and `tblMemberships` does not exist. `tblUsers` is the link between the other two tables.

```
Customer -- 1:* -- User -- 1:* -- Membership
```

(Sorry, can't include image as my reputataion < 10).

My questions are:

1. What do I need to do in order to have `tblMemberships` included?
2. Is this a recommended way of retrieve data or I should break it up into two queries? Or the design is totally rubbish?

I am using EF5, ASP .NET MVC 4

Kindly advise. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps `.Include("tblUsers.tblMemberships")` is the right way to go?

Comment: @DavidG Ahh..... good shout!Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

When you write code like this:

```
db.ParentTable
    .Include("ChildTable")
    .Include("ChildOfChildTable");
```

You are saying include all entries from `ChildTable` that are keyed to `ParentTable` and also include all entries from `ChildOfChildTable` that are ALSO keyed to `ParentTable`. Instead you need to tell Entity Framework that `ChildOfChildTable` is beneath `ChildTable` in the hierarchy, like this:

```
db.ParentTable
    .Include("ChildTable.ChildOfChildTable");
```

So this means your code should be:

```
this.dbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
List<tblCustomerInfo> customers = this.dbContext.tblCustomerInfoes
                                      .Include("tblUsers.tblMemberships")
```